# Determine coefficients of polynomial sum

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Given:
$P:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},P(x):=x^2+1$ and
$Q:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},Q(x):=1-x$
I need to determine the coefficients $a_k$, such that:
$(P+Q)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^5a_k(x-i)^k$

$(P+Q)(x)=x^2-x+2$, so I need to find coefficients, such that:
$\sum_{k=0}^5a_k(x-i)^k = x^2-x+2$

I am stuck her, there probably must exist a trick for such a kind of excersise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: LHS is quadratic, RHS is linear, coefficients won't help.

Comment: but $(P+Q)$ is quadratic again

Comment: @user3125470 Are you missing an exponent in $\sum_{k=0}^5a_k(x-i)^{\color{red}{k}}$ maybe?

Comment: @dxiv you are right, edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] so I need to find coefficients, such that: $\;\sum_{k=0}^5a_k(x-i)^k = x^2-x+2$

Hint: let $x-i=z$ so that $x=z+i\,$, then:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^5a_k z^k = (z+i)^2-(z+i)+2=z^2+(-1+2i)z+(1-i)
$$

Equating the coefficients between the two sides gives $a_0 = 1-i, \,a_1 = \dots$